# TYPO3 - Extension TCA - Show backend fields

Tags: typo3

I'm deveopping my own Typo3 extension and it's not as easy as expected :)
When i create an object in the backend it's working :

[image]

But I can't find a way to display the following commands :

- move up
- move down
- enable/disabled

Here is what I tried to show the "enable/disable" icon :

```
$TCA['tx_productsfaq_domain_model_scenario'] = array (
    'ctrl' => array (
        'enablecolumns' => [
            'disabled' => 'hidden'
        ]
    )
);
```

.. with no success. In my database the model has a "hidden" column (tinyint). Maybe I forgot something ? All other properties in my TCA work fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a sorting field in your Database

```
CREATE table tx_productsfaq_domain_model_scenario (
    ...
    sorting int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    deleted tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    hidden tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    ...
);
```

and TCA configuration like

```
$TCA['tx_productsfaq_domain_model_scenario'] = array (
    'ctrl' => [
        ...
        'sortby' => 'sorting',
        'enablecolumns' => [
            'disabled' => 'hidden'
        ],
        ...
    ]
);
```

It seems you are using the old way to configure your TCA. Please see https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/Introduction/Index.html

Use EXT:productsfaq/Configuration/TCA/tx_productsfaq_domain_model_scenario.php

```
return [
    'ctrl' => [
        ...
        'sortby' => 'sorting',
        'delete' => 'deleted',
        'enablecolumns' => [
            'disabled' => 'hidden',
        ],
        ...
    ],
    'interface' => [
        'showRecordFieldList' => 'hidden, ...'
    ],
    'types' => [
        '0' => ['showitem' => 'hidden, ...']
    ],
    'columns' => [
        ...
    ]
];
```

Comment: The "'sortby' => 'sorting'" makes my issue solved. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your TYPO3 version `move up`, `move down` will be visible if you switch on extended view and have defined a sorting field (by default it is called `sorting` with type int).

To have the correct fields and options for sorting and hiding you may use the EXT:extension_builder and generate a dummy extension to identify these fields.

---

Compare your definition and declaration of the fields ('sorting', 'hidden') in TCA and SQL(!) to a build in table like tt_content.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did create a dummy extension with the Builder but... -> same "enablecolumns" as mine, no sort or sorting properties, db fields are similar (hidden field, deleted field etc..) .. I'm lost :) !